# Prestashop - gmail smtp on ubuntu 16.04 `Expected response code 220 but got code “”, with message “”`

Tags: php, ubuntu, prestashop-1.6

I have 2 installation of prestashop:

1. prestashop 1.6.1.4, Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTSm PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20

and

2. prestashop 1.6.1.0, Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3

I set up emails to smtp.gmail.com:465, TLS, email/password.

On the first installation it works, on the second instaltion it fails with `Expected response code 220 but got code “”, with message “`

Note: I set up `two step verification` and `app password`, I verified it is working with the first installation.

Please help.

Comment: Just to be sure. Do you use digital ocean? I had this exact same problem there before. It was caused because DO blocks google's smtp for default for spam reasons.

Comment: I use AWS, but it happens only in the second installation, so it cannot be the host service. Did changing to SSL works for you?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:
change the Encryption to SSL**

In prestashop admin > Advanced Parameters >  E-mail

check `Set my own SMTP parameters (for advanced users ONLY)`

Fill the SMTP fileds

SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com

SMTP username: <****>

SMTP password: <****>

Encryption: SSL

Port: 465